# Javascript: Flatten any array values within object (nested)

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, data-structures, mapreduce

I would like to flatten **any** array values within an object e.g. like `sample` below. The solution should not just apply to `ecommerce` but literally anything that could be in the object as an array type. Example:

```
var sample = {
  price: "999",
  description: "...",
  ecommerce: {
    products: [
      {
        brand: "apple",
        category: "phone"
      },
      {
        brand: "google",
        category: "services"
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

And I would like the output to be:

```
{
  price: "999",
  description: "..."
  ecommerce: {
    products_1: {
      brand: "apple",
      category: "phone"
    },
    products_2: {
      brand: "google",
      category: "services"
    }
  }
}
```

What is the most efficient way to do this in JavaScript (ES6/7)?

Thanks in advance!

**Updated due to comment and several minuses!!! Would be nice if those who were so quick to click minuses when the question was initially asked would revoke it!**

I've tried this its completely wrong and I'm also sure theres a better functional way of doing this:

```
function flattenArray(array) {

  var obj = array.reduce((acc, cur, i) => {
    acc[i] = cur;
    return acc;
  }, {});

  return obj;
}

function cleanObject(object) {
  for (let key in object) {
    let testObject = object[key];

    if (Array.isArray(testObject)) {
      testObject = flattenArray(testObject)
    } else if (typeof(testObject) === 'object') {
      testObject = cleanObject(testObject);
    }

    return testObject;
  }

  return object;
}

var clean = cleanObject(sample);
```

**UPDATE 2:** seeing as both solutions were so fixated on `ecommerce` how would the solution work if the next object was:

```
var sample = {
  price: "999",
  description: "...",
  differentArray: [ 
    {
      brand: "apple",
      category: "phone"
    },
    {
      brand: "google",
      category: "services"
    }
  ]
};
```

Notice that not only is this different `key` its also at a different nesting level too.

Comment: How's your current implementation?

Comment: ... check out this [generically working `Array#reduce` based approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47221864/javascript-flatten-any-array-values-within-object-nested/47266505#47266505) that offers two solutions, one that comes with a simple recursion and the second making use of alternating/reciprocal recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recursively applied [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) based approach does the job for this kind of key-value bags, ... a first generic solution then might look like this one ...

```js
function recursivelyMapArrayItemsToGenericKeys(collector, key) {
  var
    source  = collector.source,
    target  = collector.target,
    type    = source[key];

  if (Array.isArray(type)) {
    type.forEach(function (item, idx) {
      var
        keyList     = Object.keys(item || ''),
        genericKey  = [key, idx].join('_');

      if (keyList.length >= 1) {
        target[genericKey] = keyList.reduce(recursivelyMapArrayItemsToGenericKeys, {

          source: item,
          target: {}

        }).target;
      } else {
        target[genericKey] = item;
      }
    });
  } else if (typeof type !== 'string') {
    var keyList = Object.keys(type || '');

    if (keyList.length >= 1) {
      target[key] = keyList.reduce(recursivelyMapArrayItemsToGenericKeys, {

        source: type,
        target: {}

      }).target;
    } else {
      target[key] = type;
    }
  } else {
    target[key] = type;
  }
  return collector;
}

var sample = {
  price: "999",
  description: "...",
  ecommerce: {
    products: [{
      brand: "apple",
      category: "phone"
    }, {
      brand: "google",
      category: "services"
    }, {
      foo: [{
        brand: "bar",
        category: "biz"
      }, {
        brand: "baz",
        category: "biz"
      }]
    }]
  }
};

var result = Object.keys(sample).reduce(recursivelyMapArrayItemsToGenericKeys, {

  source: sample,
  target: {}

}).target;

console.log('sample : ', sample);
console.log('result : ', result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

... within a next code sanitizing step one might get rid of duplicated logic, thus ending up with two functions and an alternating/reciprocal recursion ...

```js
function recursivelyAssignItemsFromTypeByKeys(target, type, keyList, key) {
  if (keyList.length >= 1) {
    target[key] = keyList.reduce(recursivelyMapArrayItemsToGenericKeys, {

      source: type,
      target: {}

    }).target;
  } else {
    target[key] = type;
  }
}

function recursivelyMapArrayItemsToGenericKeys(collector, key) {
  var
    source  = collector.source,
    target  = collector.target,
    type    = source[key];

  if (Array.isArray(type)) {
    type.forEach(function (item, idx) {
      var
        keyList     = Object.keys(item || ''),
        genericKey  = [key, idx].join('_');

      recursivelyAssignItemsFromTypeByKeys(target, item, keyList, genericKey);
    });
  } else if (typeof type !== 'string') {
    var keyList = Object.keys(type || '');

    recursivelyAssignItemsFromTypeByKeys(target, type, keyList, key);
  } else {
    target[key] = type;
  }
  return collector;
}

var sample = {
  price: "999",
  description: "...",
  ecommerce: {
    products: [{
      brand: "apple",
      category: "phone"
    }, {
      brand: "google",
      category: "services"
    }, {
      foo: [{
        brand: "bar",
        category: "biz"
      }, {
        brand: "baz",
        category: "biz"
      }]
    }]
  }
};

var result = Object.keys(sample).reduce(recursivelyMapArrayItemsToGenericKeys, {

  source: sample,
  target: {}

}).target;

console.log('sample : ', sample);
console.log('result : ', result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks Peter for answering the question - with the example this certainly looks like it does the job. Up voting and will post back if there any issues. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do :

```js
const sample = {
  price: "999",
  description: "...",
  ecommerce: {
    products: [
      {
        brand: "apple",
        category: "phone"
      },
      {
        brand: "google",
        category: "services"
      }
    ]
  }
}

sample.ecommerce.products.forEach((p, i) => {
  sample.ecommerce['products_' + i] = p
})

delete sample.ecommerce.products

console.log(sample)
```

Comment: Thanks. However what I'd like is for this to be agnostic and not just apply to specific use case of `ecommerce.products` - the object I'll be getting back will have unknown key/values which may or may not be an array

Answer (score 0):

Just [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=b) `ecommerce` array and destruct each element as you wish.

```js
const sample = {
  price: "999",
  description: "...",
  ecommerce: {
    products: [
      {
        brand: "apple",
        category: "phone"
      },
      {
        brand: "google",
        category: "services"
      }
    ]
  }
}

const flattenArray = (arr, key) =>
  arr.reduce((prev, curr, index) => {
    return {
      ...prev,
      [`${key}_${index + 1}`]: curr,
    }
  }, {})
  
const result = {
  ...sample,
  ecommerce: flattenArray(sample.ecommerce.products, 'products'),
}

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks seems pretty close but as per previous answer this is quite specific to `ecommerce` part of the object - I'd would need to nest as many deep as possible over all key/value pairs, identify if its an array and then flatten accordingly.